# Possible to use Gnome-Software to update software?

Tags: software-center, update-manager, gnome-software

Is it possible to use Gnome-Software to install updates?

Answer (score 0):

Many updates, but not all. There's a lot more to Ubuntu and Linux than GNOME knows. In addition, you are almost always better off sticking with what's in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: https://apps.ubuntu.com nowadays takes you to https://snapcraft.io/store which is not GNOME Software.

Comment: That's not at all what you seemed to be asking in the question above. You seemed to be asking if you could replace update-manager. You might wish to edit the question so others don't get confused.

Comment: Other distros are able to use gnome-software to update all system packages.